# Установить соединение

Tags: lan, ethernet

Можно ли установить соединение между 2 ноутбуками с помощью ethernet(lan кабель).Тип чтоб можно было передавать файлы,играть и т.д.Если да,то как?Было бы хорошо,если б поподробнее объяснили,потому что в этой части я слаб.

Comment: @faksel забыл отметить,что у одного убунту,а у одного виндоус

Comment: попробуй http://profhelp.com.ua/articles/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E

Answer (score 0):

если винда то заходите на каждом компе в сетевое окружение - адаптеры - свойство - настройка ipv4 и прописываете различные ip, например 192.168.1.10 для одного и 192.168.1.11 для другого. нажимаете на поле с маской, нажимаете внизу ок. Иногда требуется отключить брандмауэр или антивирус, если подключить не удастся

Comment: Я ж говорю,что у одного компа убунту 18.04,а у одного виндоус 10

Answer (score 0):

Первое - надо решить, какой протокол применить. Впрочем, тут почти без вариантов IPv4.

Второе - выбрать подсеть и адреса для каждого из компьютеров. Например, пусть будет [предложенная](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/882485/229437) товарищем  [@Roman Kh.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/309616/roman-kh) подсеть 192.168.0.0 с маской 255.255.255.0. Одному компу дадим адрес, например, 192.168.0.10 с маской 255.255.255.0 (возможная альтернативная нотация 192.168.0.10/24), второму 192.168.0.11 с маской 255.255.255.0 (возможная альтернативная нотация 192.168.0.11/24). Поскольку они будут связаны только между собой, то ни шлюз, ни адрес DNS или иных серверов не требуется.

Теперь осталось для каждой ОС выполнить настройку и присвоить выбранные адрес и маску. Как это делать, подробно рассказывается во встроенной справке каждой ОС, да и онлайн-документов с порядком настройки - море.

И опять же как [предложено](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/882485/229437) выше - поотключать брэндмауэры-файрволы-антивирусы - Вы же не собираетесь друг друга хакать или вирями заражать?